# Solving the differential equation $x^2y''+xy'-y=x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x^2y''+xy'-y=x^2$$

**My attempt:**

Divided by $x^2$:

$$y''+\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=1$$

Now to solve the homogenous equation using Euler's method

$$y''+\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=0$$

To look for solution $y=x^r$

so $y'=rx^{r-1}$

$y''=r(r-1)x^{r-2}$

So:

$$r(r-1)x^{r-2}+\frac{rx^{r-1}}{x}-\frac{x^r}{x^2}=0$$

Divided by $x^r$:

$$r(r-1)x^{-2}+\frac{rx^{-1}}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$

Is it correct so far?

> My problem:
>    I don't know how to find $r_1,r_2$

Comment: Multiply by $x^2$.

Comment: @AlexS I'm trying to solve this over an hour, I don't know how I missed it

Comment: It happens to everybody from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$r(r-1)x^{-2}+\frac{rx^{-1}}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$ Multiplying through by $x^2$ yields $$r(r-1) + r - 1 = 0 \iff r = \pm 1$$

So that you get your complementary solution as $y = x$ and $y = \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

As per ChickenP's answer,

$y_c = Ax + \dfrac{B}{x}$

Now since the D.E. is linear, also account for a particular solution, i.e.

$y_p = s \cdot x^2$ so $y'' + \dfrac{y'}{x} - \dfrac{y}{x^2} = 2s + 2s -s = 3s = 1$ giving $s = \frac{1}{3}$, so $y_p = \frac{1}{3}x^2$

Then the full solution is

> $y = Ax + \dfrac{B}{x} + \frac{1}{3}x^2$

Comment: Could you explain why y_p = s * x^2 and where the 2s+2s-s come from?